# Make a meta strip show the audio waveform

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have a meta strip which contains a video file and an audio file. I can clearly see the waveform in the audio file. However if I create a meta strip out of these two strips the audio waveform disappears. How do I create a meta strip which shows the audio waveform?

Answer (score 0):

As of blender 4.0, there is no current built in way to show the audio waveform on a meta strip that has an audio strip within it.